# Is aws-amplify with auth broken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to build a react app which will use the aws hosted ui for authentication. I am trying to use aws-amplify to achieve this, and so far I am having no such luck.

[Here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#configuring-the-hosted-ui) the docs state that the auth config should look like this.

```
const oauth = {
  domain : 'your-domain-prefix.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com', 
  scope : ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid','aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'], 
  redirectSignIn : 'http://www.example.com/signin/', 
  redirectSignOut : 'http://www.example.com/signout/',
  responseType: 'code',
}
```

But when I use this config setup I get the following error.

> The parameters: App client Id, App web domain, the redirect URL when
>   you are signed in and the redirect URL when you are signed out are
>   required.

As you can see, those params are clearly supplied. So I clicked on the source map file linked in my console with the error message, and saw this.

```
if (data == null || !ClientId || !AppWebDomain || !RedirectUriSignIn || !RedirectUriSignOut) {
      throw new Error(this.getCognitoConstants().PARAMETERERROR);
    }
```

Which makes it seem more like the config should look a little something like this.

```
const auth = {
  AppWebDomain: "aaaaa",
  TokenScopesArray: ["phone", "email", "profile", "openid", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"],
  RedirectUriSignIn: "http://localhost:3000",
  RedirectUriSignOut: "http://localhost:3000",
  responseType: "token",
  ClientId: "aaa",
  UserPoolId: "aaa",
};
```

But when doing this, and trying to send the user to the hosted ui as the docs say [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#launching-the-hosted-ui-in-react) I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined

Once again I looked at the source and found this.

```
var domain = config.domain,
```

Which makes it seem like its expecting the config which does not work.

At this point I am really lost and can use any help at all.

Comment: Can you also post (or check again) your cognito configuration from aws (clientWeb of your App client settings, Domain name) ? These entries have to be the same in both your app and aws.

Answer (score 12):

Going through the `Auth.ts` code, it appears that you have to include the `userPoolId` and `userPoolWebClientId` fields, in addition to `oauth`. Here's how I got it to work:

```
const oauth = {
  domain: 'XXXXXX.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com',
  scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
  redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  responseType: 'code'
};
Auth.configure({
  oauth: oauth,
  region: 'us-west-2',
  userPoolId: 'us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX',
  userPoolWebClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
```